# Passing data to widget in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I made a very simple custom widget, however I want to add it to the editor via a custom button instead of a toolbar button so I use `editor.execCommand("mywidget")`. The widget is added correctly, but how do I pass data to the widget via this `execCommand` call? In the [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-execCommand) it says that the second parameter to `execCommand` is used to pass data to the command handler, however I can't seem to find HOW do I access that in the widget code after I call `execCommand("mywidget", {paramshere})`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget) were already updated for CKEditor 4.5.0 Beta and the ability to specify widget data through the command is a new feature of this version.

So, since CKEditor 4.5.0 Beta this is (will be) possible:

```
editor.execCommand( 'simplebox', {
    startupData: {
        align: 'left'
    }
} );
```

But before this version you need to use the Widget API directly. See how the [command works now in 4.5.0 Beta](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/ca891bb/plugins/widget/plugin.js#L1782-L1843). There's quite a lot of code, but most of it is about opening the dialog and handling the widget element before it is even inserted into editor (it must be kept somewhere).

If you only want to insert a widget, then simply follow the [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget):

```
var element = editor.document.createElement( 'div' );
editor.insertElement( element );
var widget = editor.widgets.initOn( element, 'simplebox', { align: 'left' } );
```

As you can see [`widgetsRepository.initOn()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.repository-method-initOn) accepts the data object.

Comment: I updated docs to avoid this confusion in the future - https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/commit/2c51ef1f437c98e9a6a73b545ecba693ba14ecd0

Comment: Dumb question - but how do I receive this command in the widget - is it the exec function? Based on the data passed I need to generate my template - can the `template` be a function, or can it be assigned in the exec function? @Reinmar

Comment: Yep - I saw this post you made: http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/help-Inserting-a-widget-from-my-own-button -- wondering if there is a way to intercept that command and change the template based on the data passed through execCommand

Comment: I've managed to do what I needed in `beforeCommandExec` (by checking command name and assigning a template)

Answer (score 1):

When you define the command, or if you need to modify and existing command, you simply need to add a second parameter to the exec function like so:

```js
   function myCommandName(data){
     this.data = data
   } 
   myCommandName.prototype = {
     exec: function(editor, data) {
       if(data){
         doSomethingWithData(data);
       }
     }
   }
   editor.addCommand( 'myCommandName', new myCommandName(optionalDefaultData) )
```

To pass the data to the command upon execution, provide the data as the second attribute after the command name.

```
editor.execCommand('myCommandName', { data: 'my data' });
```